# error: excess elements in char array initializer

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating a weather report for college assignment. I working on a function that is suppose to print out the data for all 12 months. I have an array that is 12 in size and holds the name of the 12 months. When I compile the program I keep getting the following error:

```
assignment3.c:149:5: error: excess elements in char array initializer
```

Here is the function that has this array:

```
    void printMonthlyStatistic(int month,const struct MonthlyStatistic* monthly){

    int i;
    char monthNames[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
                           "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    for (i=0;i<12;i++) {

        printf(" %c | %.1f | %.1f | %.1f | %.1f \n",monthNames[i],monthly->maxTemperature,monthly->minTemperature,monthly->averageTemperature,
                                                    monthly->totalPrecipitation);
    }

}
```

Comment: It should be `char* monthNames[12]`.

Comment: Note that this assumes you code January as month 0, and December as month 11.  The standard C library does that in `struct tm`; most other code does not.

Comment: Instead of all the suggestions to use `const char *monthNames[12]` (which certainly work). you could also use `const char monthNames[12][10] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};`  On a 64-bit system, this uses less space (120 bytes) than the array of pointers (96 bytes) plus the strings (86 bytes).  OTOH, on 64-bit systems, 64 bytes or so really doesn't matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excess elements in char array initializer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024433/excess-elements-in-char-array-initializer-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined an array of individual `char` values and since the elements are string literals and consist of more than one character there are excess elements in your initializer and hence the error message.

Instead you could define an array of `char*` where each element will point to the start of each string literal in the array.

```
const char* monthNames[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

As these strings will probably end up in the read only data segment of your binary. It wont hurt to declare them `const`.

Comment: OP has only posted one line of code, which is ill-formed (but was supposed to be both a declaration and a definition).  There's no array of 12 char pointers in OP's code, and no mismatch between declaration and definition.

Comment: OP has tried to define an array of 12 char values but provided an initializer containing 12 string literals

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
char monthNames[12]
```

represents an array of char, not a string, but a single character.
You must change your array to something like this:

```
char* montNames[12]
```

in order to have an array of strings and not a simple character.