# Excess elements in char array initializer error

Tags: c, arrays, char

I've been trying to execute the following code.. However, I keep getting the same errors over and over again and I don't know why!

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    int randomNum;
    char takenWords[4];
    char words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};


    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        do{
            randomNum = (rand()%20);
        takenWords[i]=words[randomNum];
        }while((strcmp(&words[randomNum], takenWords) == 0)&&((strcmp(&words[randomNum], &takenWords[i])==0)));
        printf("%s\n", &words[randomNum]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I have counted the number of elements which I entered in the array and they do not exceed 20!

Also, why do I keep getting the 'Implicit conversion loses integer precision error'?

Comment: Please post your code here, not through link

Comment: `char words[20]` is an array of 20 `char`s, but you need an array of 20 pointers to char (`char*`). There are more issues. Read chapter about strings in your C textbook.

Comment: Just replace " by ' ,  means instead of "Dog" use 'Dog'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you want to make arrays of pointers instead of arrays of characters.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    int randomNum;
    const char *takenWords[4];
    const char *words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};


    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        int dupe=0;
        do{
            randomNum = (rand()%20);
            takenWords[i]=words[randomNum];
            dupe=0;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                if(strcmp(words[randomNum],takenWords[j])==0)dupe=1;
            }
        }while(dupe);
        printf("%s\n", words[randomNum]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, exactly as I wished! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 7):

```
char words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};
```

Look at the array you have declared closely. what does it contains?

String literals (i.e. `"DOG"` and other string literals).

Look at the array itself, it is declared to store `char`

```
char words[20]
```

Thats the error.

---

To store string literals, you need `pointer to char`, that is `char *`

Since you have an array of string literals, you need an array of `char *`

```
char* words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};
```

---

Since you are using the other array also to point to string literals, declare them the same way

```
char* takenWords[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in your code `char words[20]` is an array to hold a single string/word of 20 characters but not 20 different strings.

> However in order to declare 20 different strings use a 2D array this
>   way char words[20][20] and then continue to declare the strings/words
>   of your choice of maximum 20 length.

```
 char words[20][20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};
```

**Note:** `char words[20][20]` represents an array to hold 20 strings of maximum length 20 characters...

> generally `char words[m][n]` where m,n are integers holds m strings of
>   max length **(n-1 chars)+(terminating null character)**.

Comment: More generally, `char array[m][n];` can hold `m` strings of `n-1` characters + terminating null-character.

Answer (score -1):

char arr[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE]
declare maximum string size that's it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is in need of a little more context and formatting. For more help, see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).